# Keep getting record_invalid while using FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A lot of times, when I use FactoryGirl in my specs, I keep receiving errors like:

```
Failure/Error: f = FactoryGirl.build(:my_model)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       translation missing: de.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid
```

Now, if I start a console in test mode, I get a record back, and I don't get any errors.
How should I proceed with this?

EDIT: I was missing the translation and did not see the relevant message. After I switched to a `:en` locale, the errors were clear.

Comment: Validation was failing because some associations were not set up.

Comment: @Geo can you specify the solution? I have the same problem!

Comment: Sorry. I see your EDIT comment now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can't build your model, because it requires some parameters during initialization. Use `initialize_with`:

```
factory :user do
  name "John Doe"

  initialize_with { new(name) }
end
```

Look at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction for details